# Unity Animator SetTrigger not resetting to default

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As I hopefully correctly understand the Animator "SetTrigger" will set the animation to false once it's done (correct me if I'm wrong), but this is not the case for my project.

I have two states. Default (do nothing) and Move. Default is automatically entered when the app is opened and Move is triggered when I call "SetTrigger". I expect that Animator will set this animation id to false once the animation is done and then go back to Default state. but this is not the case - animation keeps repeating. I can achieve this by calling "ResetTrigger" manually but then I need to detect when the animation is done, which is not convenient in my case.

I want to achieve that animation is played only once when called. Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: Adding animation controller

[image]

```
public class TestAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Animator _animation;
    private static readonly int Playing = Animator.StringToHash("PlayingTrigger");

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        _animation = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            _animation.SetTrigger(Playing);
         //   _animation.ResetTrigger(Playing);

            IDebug.Log("Playing animation ");
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            _animation.ResetTrigger(Playing);
            IDebug.Log("reseting animation ");
        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Its a little bit hard to explaing whitout an image of the animator interface but you can create bool variables and asociate it in the conditions of transitions (arrows) betwen the animations. In a way that when you active than boolean in a script the animation starts and when you put it in false the animation stops. I hope that this help you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the Animator "SetTrigger" will set the animation to false once it's done

-> **Nope!**

The only thing it does is resetting the **trigger** itself once it was used for a transition, it doesn't mean the animation state is reset once the animation has reached the end.

If you want your Animator go back to the idle/default state after your animation is done then in the controller add a [transition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html)

```
yourState -> Idle/Default
```

with

- Has Exit Time -> True
- Duration -> as you like
- Exit Time -> 1 - Duration

No further condition.

Otherwise you might be rather looking for a **Bool** parameter and `Animator.SetBool` instead

---

Also note one further pitfall: **The triggers can stack!**

This means if you call 5 times `SetTrigger` then that trigger will be used for 5 transitions until it is finally reset and doesn't trigger the transition anymore!

Therefore I ended up using a trigger resetter directly attached not to a specific state but the **Basic layer itself** -> it is automatically called for each and every entered state:

```
public class TriggerResetter : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        foreach(var p in animator.parameters)
        {
            if (p.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Trigger)
            {
                animator.ResetTrigger(p.name);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However it still doesnt transition to the default state (blue transition arrow), with the parameters I've defined like you said. (please check the edit on original post)

Comment: Are you sure it is not just immediately transitioned back again?

Comment: For the test I just press the keyboard button. It transitions to default If in that complete state I press the activate button again. So i'm quite positive... the blue line in eye_move doesn't move..

Comment: Just did. Please check it out.

Comment: This sounds like you have still a condition on the transition back using the same trigger like for the transition towards that eye_move state .. can you show the transition settings for both?

Comment: I actually ended up deleting the transition and creating a new one (from move to default). It works now. You've helped a lot, thanks! By the way.. what does Exit time actually do? What if it's less then 1?

Comment: "Afaik the triggers can stack" - this was my problem, calling `animator.ResetTrigger(animHash)` fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @derHugo pointed out; the trigger itself gets reset but not the actual animation. It was bugging me for a while. The fix is pretty simple, all you need to do is make the transition back to the previous state(from which the trigger was triggered).